# IE10 line-height bug with display:inline-block; and overflow:hidden;

Tags: overflow, internet-explorer-10, css

I've recently run in to a peculiar problem in IE10 (*sigh*). It appears that if you use display:inline-block; in conjunction with overflow:hidden; IE10 messes up your line-height.
I tried fixing it using vertical-align:middle; but that only almost fixes the problem in IE10 and then introduces baseline problems in other browsers.

The only code needed to trigger the bug is:

**CSS:**

```
.bug {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>This should <span class="bug">be buggy</span> in IE10</p>
```

I created a JSFiddle to illustrate the bug - http://jsfiddle.net/laustdeleuran/5pWMQ/.

There's also a screenshot of the bug here - https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3d0t1m3h00462w2n1s0Q/Image%202013-04-08%20at%2011.13.16%20AM.png?v=2688e27a

**EDIT:**

This is not a IE10 bug (but more a case of lazy testing on my behalf). Actually Chrome (webkit) is the one doing it wrong - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15883508/799327.

Comment: The output matches the screenshot in every non-WebKit browser for me, including older versions of IE. Only current Chrome keeps the same vertical alignment. Call me biased, but I think this is a bug with WebKit, not IE.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. Just didn't think that was a possibility. Stupid me.

Comment: have you fixed this issue yet ?

Comment: @Twocode, yeah - but it's not really a fix. It's (was?) a WebKit issue. See the fiddle below for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) says

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

which is exactly what IE10 is doing.

And Firefox and Opera are doing the same thing.

It's not IE that's bugged, it's Chrome, which is not following the above rule correctly.

Comment: Argh, so this is just me being caught pretending that we have a webkit-monoculture. Which I really don't want. 

Anyway, thanks for the quick response, will have to look into another way to fix this :)

Comment: So, the standards wording set me on the right path to get what I want. I just need to use vertical-align:bottom;. I've updated the JSFiddle to reflect this: http://jsfiddle.net/laustdeleuran/5pWMQ/