# css inline width property not working in ie10

Tags: css

I am using a checkbox whose inline style is

```
style="width: 12px; height: 20px; visibility: visible;"
```

It works fine in IE 8,9,11 but not working in IE 10.

Comment: Add the HTML to the question.

Comment: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882836/ie10-line-height-bug-with-displayinline-block-and-overflowhidden) to your question

Comment: Add style : overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;

Comment: <input name="LockRate" tabindex="0" id="LockRate" style="width: 12px; height: 20px; visibility: visible;" type="checkbox">

Comment: added display:inline-block; not working. The problem is the checkbox is displaying in small size but works perfect in different version of IE.